# Error after installing CUDA on WSL 2 - RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA on WSL 2 for running a project that uses TorchAudio and PyTorch. I have done the steps exactly according to the documentation [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html).

However, when I run my required code, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

For reference, I have an NVIDIA RTX 2060, and my NVIDIA driver is installed correctly as well. Are there any recommended next steps/known solutions for this?

Some additional information, I am using the latest Windows preview build as expected, and my Ubuntu version is 20.04 (directly downloaded from the Microsoft store).

Comment: I assume you mean "Preview", rather than "previous"? ;-)  Also, you are missing the hyperlink on "documentation here" - I assume you meant to link to https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, they were typing issues. Do you have any insight into this error?

Comment: I do wish I had some insight on the actual error, but unfortunately I don't.  I see that you originally had this on Stack Overflow, and I think that's the better place for it.  I see a number of WSL2/Cuda questions and answers there.  I can't be sure, but your question there was probably closed because you didn't provide enough details (code sample), even though I'm sure your code was the same as in the example.  I'd recommend trying to improve the question on Stack Overflow, since you'll have a better audience there that can help.  I'll upvote your question there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have cuda toolkit installed and everything is in place (nvidia-smi in WSL working and everything). Downgrading your pytorch version from 1.10 to 1.8.2LTS might help, this worked for me,  previous attempts that others report working for them (but didn't for me) is to downgrade your NVidia display driver to 472.12 instead of 5xx.

```sh
pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cu111 torchvision==0.9.2+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
```